# How to have arrows for moving the cursor up and down when writing text on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, keyboard

When writing paragraph on iPhone, I need to quickly move the cursor up and down so that I can go to lines above and below respectively.

Although, you can do this by touch and holding the cursor, and then moving it to wherever you want, I specifically need to have a keyboard stroke.

When filling up forms, you see the up and down keys.

[image]

Is there any keyboard out there that has this feature?

Comment: A third party keyboard might have such feature. I don't know anany but I know some applications have this feature. For example, I use Bear for general note taking and it has a toolbar with arrows that do just thWI. It sits on top of the keyboard. [Here's a picture of it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oi2Cg.png) It's taken on an iPad, but it's really just the same on an iPhone as well.

Comment: Yeah. Some apps (Bear, Todoist) have their own keyboard enhancements. Was looking for iPhone notes  app.

Answer (score -1):

The arrows you see in your screenshot move the cursor to the previous or next form input field, they do not navigate within a text field to go to previous or following lines. If you have a phone supporting 3D Touch, you can force press on the stock iOS keyboard to quickly move the cursor (the phone will vibrate and the letters will disappear, then the keyboard area acts like a touchpad to control the cursor). If your phone does not support 3D Touch, you double tap and keep your fingers on the screen on the second tap for the same effect.